# If there is no value, how can I catch an err?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to make log in & registration function.

when i try to log in, If I entered wrong id I want to show err log.
but this isn't working .

> else if(row.id==''){
>            alert("wrong id");
>          }

If I put wrong id, then the query wouldn't work.

how can I catch an err and show on log?

```
function loginConfirm2() {
  var id = $('#id').val();
  var s_id = "'" + id + "'";
  var pw = $('#password').val();
  var pw = '' + pw;
  var d_id = '';
  var d_pw = '';
  if (id) {
    db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');
    db.each("SELECT id, pw FROM user where id=" + s_id, function(err, row) {
      d_id = row.id;
      d_pw = row.pw;
      if ((id == row.id) && (pw == row.pw)) {
        window.location.href = "distribute_download.html?id=" + id;
      }
      else if(row.id==''){
         alert("wrong id");
       }
      else if(!(pw == row.pw)){
         alert("wrong pw");
       }
      else if(row.id==''){
         alert("wrong id");
       }
       else if(row.pw=='undefined'){
          alert("wrong pw");
        };
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
    db.close();
  }
}
function insultMember2() {
  var id = $('#id').val();
  var pw = $('#password').val();
  db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');
  db.run("INSERT into user(id,pw) VALUES(?,?)", [id, pw], function(err, row) {});
  db.close();
  window.location.href = "finishedJoin.html";
};
```

**db**

this is how I make db.
another problem is this alter shows few times
I guess it because in my db there some same data?

> else if(!(pw == row.pw)){
>                alert("wrong pw");
>              }

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');
db.serialize(function() {

  db.run("CREATE TABLE if not exists user (id STRING, pw STRING)");
  db.each("SELECT id, pw FROM user", function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.id + ": " + row.pw);
  });
  db.each("SELECT id, pw FROM user where id='qwe'", function(err, row) {
    console.log("db에 저장된 id는" + row.id);
  });
});
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each() method if the result set is empty, the callback is never called.
So instead of using each() use get since "id" will be one

```
var sql = "SELECT id, pw FROM user where id=?";
        db.get( sql, [s_id], (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
            } else {
            if(row){
                d_id = row.id;
                d_pw = row.pw;
                if ((id == row.id) && (pw == row.pw)) {
                    window.location.href = "distribute_download.html?id=" + id;
                }
                else if(row.id == ''){
                    alert("wrong id");
                }
                else if(!(pw == row.pw) || row.pw == 'undefined' || row.pw == undefined){
                    alert("wrong pw");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Wrong ID");
            }
}
        });
```

`

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: when i put wrong id, [row.id] have this error
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Statement.db.get.
--> in Database#get('SELECT id, pw FROM user where id=?', [ '45' ], [Function])
    at loginConfirm2 
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick `

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some more information about error? like full stack trace and mean while can you please try and check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks! I fixted it! everything works fine! except when I put non-existent id. it shows notting, no errer..no logs..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757417/how-can-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-user-id-exists 
this is my new question! could you check it out?