# How can I check in SQLite whether a user id exists?

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, electron

I want to check that if user puts wrong id shows error.

I tried like this, but didn't work.

when I put wrong is, it shows notting, no error, no log, didn't go to next page.

I'm using sqlite3 in electron

> if (err) {
>
> return console.error(err.message);
>
> alert("no id exist"); }

```
  var sql = "SELECT id, pw FROM user where id=?";
        db.get( sql, [id], (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
              alert("no id exist"); //not working!!!
            }
            console.log("db id"+row.id);
            console.log("db pw"+row.pw);
            if(row){
                d_id = row.id;
                d_pw = row.pw;
                if ((id == row.id) && (pw == row.pw)) {
                    window.location.href = "pause_and_download_multi_function.html?id=" + id;
                }
                else if(row.id == ''){
                    alert("wrong id");
                }
                else if(!(pw == row.pw) || row.pw == 'undefined' || row.pw == undefined){
                    alert("wrong pw");
                }
            } else {
                alert("wrong id");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You are using browser functions in a server script.

Comment: @DanD. oh I'm using electron. I editted a question

Comment: I guess the issue is that you `return`-ed at the `console.error` and `alert` is not reached, and (I guess) these codes are ran on the browser thread, so the error is logged at devtool instead of terminal running npm run start, as a result you are not seeing anything on the terminal.

Comment: Question already exist. [Check this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416004/6401829)